# Why is my popupMenuStyle not being applied? (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

Following the answer given here, I've tried applying a custom background to my overflow menu, but am having no luck. I know that my "AppTheme" is being applied because the `actionBarStyle` is being applied.

The problem is that "MyPopupMenu" is not being applied.

Here is my styles.xml in my values-v11 folder:

```
<color name="custom_theme_action_bar_color">#0288d1</color>
<color name="custom_theme_action_bar_text_color">#ffffff</color>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/custom_theme_action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/custom_theme_action_bar_text_color</item>
</style>
```